# How to read RRD file to get usage data?

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

I have setup a mrtg setup with `rrdtool`. Now I'm planning to get incoming outgoing usage data from these RRD files and failing to find a correct way to do it.

Can anyone show we how to get those usage data from rrd files?
Then I can maintain a db to keep those usage data and calculate the cost etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use `rrdtool graph ... PRINT:xxx` or rather `rrdtool xport ...` to get data out of the rrd file. If you want to get to the actual data, use `rrdtool fetch`.

you can find tons of additional info on http://rrdtool.org

Comment: Thank you Tobi :) I found a useful command 'rrdtool fetch xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_gi0_1.123.rrd AVERAGE -r 300' and I'm now playing with it. Let me explain my problem here;                                        I was using mrtg setup with .log files and now I have convert it to rrdtool. I was collecting usage from .log files every 5 minute and now I want to do the same thing with RRD files. I hope this can be done using rrdtool fetch. Any advice appreciate.

Comment: Hi Tobi Oetiker, I use 'rrdtool fetch xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx_gi0_x.xxxx.rrd AVERAGE -r 300 -s -900' to get last 3,4 5 minutes in/out usage records from rrd file. But I cannot file any similarities if I compare it with the data of log file (the graphs are same). Please help!

Comment: don't know what is going wrong for you ... if the graph is the same, so should the data ... if you use -s 900 you get the time slot from 15 minute ago, so maybe this is an issue.

Comment: I cannot  understand a single word of what your are trying to explain.  sorry.  How do I fill the `...` in?

Comment: The ... stand for whatever rrdtool graph commands you use in your scenario

Comment: I am getting syntax error when I am using this. rrdtool fetch my.rrd