# How to get data from ganglia's database

Tags: ganglia

I want use ganglia's data to analyze our cluster, But I don't know where is the ganglia's database.

Anyone had do this before?

Answer (score 4):

It is rrd files that stores metrics data on gmetad. usually the default path is `/var/lib/ganglia/rrds/<cluster-name>/<node-name>/` where each metric is stored in a single rrd file like `bytes_in.rrd`

Please refer to command [rrdfetch](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdfetch.en.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494114/how-to-read-rrd-file-to-get-usage-data) to see how to fetch data from rrd file (this is pure rrdtool question which is out of ganglia technology)

Answer (score 4):

To get data from ganglia .rrd files and save it in .xml file, you can use rddtool.

```
rrdtool dump filename.rrd [filename.xml] [--header|-h {none,xsd,dtd}] [--no-header] [--daemon address] > filename.xml
```

example:

```
sudo rrdtool dump bytes_out.rrd > data.xml
```