# How to find the CPU consummed last day on Hadoop without Ambari

Tags: shell, hadoop, ganglia

I would like to know how to find the CPU consumed last day on my Hadoop cluster without Ambari, because I will need to use a Shell script.

I have ganglia up and running, I can see the graph for the CPU last day on Ambari.
If ganglia can give you this result, I suppose it saved the data somewhere?
What file? And how can I get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data from ganglia's database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760128/how-to-get-data-from-ganglias-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered here  [How to get data from ganglia's database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760128/how-to-get-data-from-ganglias-database)

To summarize the answer above

1. The ganglia RRD location is at /var/lib/ganglia/rrds
2. To dump a particular RRD file as plain text use the "rrdtool" command

Both the above info is captured in the question linked above

Comment: Hi Deba, Thank you for your help. I will try it and let you know ;-).